# How to reliably get outgoing masking of IP address?

Tags: perl, proxy, libcurl, lwp, tor

How can I quickly and reliably mask my outgoing IP for doing many web requests?

1. Tor is too slow. It takes 10x longer.
2. Tor Tunnel did not work at all for me http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/tortunnel/
3. CPAN WWW::FreeProxyListsCom.pm is failing cpan build tests.
4. CPAN WWW::FreeProxy is not returned any results
5. CPAN HTTP::ProxySelector is not returning any results

Can someone give some good advice on this? What is the best way to proceed?

Disclaimer :
I am working on collecting data from a gov. website that is actively blocking connections. This data is for the public good and the web admins are not doing the public service to provide the information.  This is not a shady project but for the public service.

you can inspect my code so far here 
https://code.launchpad.net/~jamesmikedupont/aspxezxs/aspxtraktor

any help with this would be appreciated, also people who would like to donate some CPU/BW.

Comment: [`WWW::FreeProxyLists` seems to work best with Perl <=v5.8.8](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=WWW-FreeProxyListsCom+0.002). Is using an older perl an option?

Comment: @mob i will try it out, good to know, also I can try and fix the code. 1 kan p3rl!

Comment: Of course, you could pay for a [VPN service](https://torrentfreak.com/which-vpn-providers-really-take-anonymity-seriously-111007/).

Comment: @ikegami that sounds like a good idea! I will research into it.

Comment: @ikegami I am trying acevpn.com now. It looks good. Will update when I have more info. thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ikegami what about acceptable use policy, they said that it would be against it.